# ReactJS custom tristate checkbox will not show checkmark

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to create a tristate checkbox using React.  I'm compiling with gulp-react 3.0.1 and have tested in Chrome and Edge w/o any luck.
The goal is to use the checkbox in a To Do list, and I like to have an "in progress" state, so the sequence should be:

- unchecked checkbox (empty square)
- click
- unchecked radio button (empty circle)
- click
- checked checkbox (square w/ checkmark)
- repeat (next click goes back to unchecked checkbox)

What I actually get with the code below is:

- unchecked checkbox (empty square)
- click
- unchecked radio button (empty circle)
- click
- **unchecked checkbox (empty square) -> THE PROBLEM**
- repeat

Samples I've seen indicate the code below might work, but I've had no luck.  I've tested my values and tried eliminating the change of 'type' w/o any effect. Any suggestions are welcome:

```
var TriState = React.createClass({
    State: { undone: 1, inprogress: 2, done: 3 },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { inputType: "checkbox", checkState: false, triState: this.State.undone };
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <span>
                <input type={this.state.inputType} checked={this.state.checkState} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
                {this.props.children}
            </span>
            );
    },
    changeHandler: function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        switch (this.state.triState) {
            case this.State.undone:
                this.setState({ inputType: "radio", checkState: false, triState: this.State.inprogress });
                break;
            case this.State.inprogress:
                this.setState({ inputType: "checkbox", checkState: true, triState: this.State.done });
                break;
            case this.State.done:
                this.setState({ inputType: "checkbox", checkState: false, triState: this.State.undone });
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `checked={this.state.checkState}` try making the truthy checkstate be `'checked'`

Comment: I expected that to work as well, but it doesn't seem to. Using: `<input type={this.state.inputType} checked={this.state.checkState ? "checked" : ""} onChange={this.changeHandler} />` results in he following in Inspect Element for the checked property (absent) in all three modes: `<input type="radio" data-reactid=".0.0">`

Comment: Could be you need to use `defaultChecked` as in https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `evt.preventDefault();` from your `changeHandler`.
You're now preventing the default behaviour of actually checking the checkbox.

Comment: That's very close.  Remember that I want it to not become checked when transitioning between undone and inprogress.  Final code below.

Comment: @VanKichline I thought you only wanted it to be checked after the unchecked radio button (done stage), my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
var TriState = React.createClass({
    Mode: { undone: 1, inprogress: 2, done: 3 },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { mode: this.Mode.undone };
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <span>
                <input ref="triState" type={this.state.mode === this.Mode.inprogress ? "radio" : "checkbox"} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
                <span onMouseUp={this.clickHandler}> {this.props.children}</span>
            </span>
            );
    },
    changeHandler: function (evt) {
        switch (this.state.mode) {
            case this.Mode.undone:
                this.setState({ mode: this.Mode.inprogress });
                evt.preventDefault();
                break;
            case this.Mode.inprogress:
                this.setState({ mode: this.Mode.done });
                break;
            case this.Mode.done:
                this.setState({ mode: this.Mode.undone });
                break;
        }
    },
    clickHandler: function () {
        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.triState).click();
    }
});
```